# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Can't load module 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll' as it's linked with 14.29, but the core is linked with 14.16

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, xampp, windows-10

Please help me

I am having an issue while the Laravel MongoDB connection.
when running this command :"composer require jenssegers/mongodb".
I got this warning message:

***LENOVO@DESKTOP-7MHNLPS MINGW64 /c/xampp8/htdocs/mongotest
$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Can't load module 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll' as it's linked with 14.29, but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Can't load module 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll' as it's linked with 14.29, but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^3.9 for jenssegers/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update jenssegers/mongodb
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires jenssegers/mongodb ^3.9 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.9.0].
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.9.0 requires illuminate/support ^9.0 -> found illuminate/support[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require jenssegers/mongodb:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require jenssegers/mongodb:^2.1" if you know which you need.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.***

I am using XAMPP on windows 10 and my PHP version is 8.1.6 and MongoDB version is 5.0.8.
I have tried three different php_mongodb.dll.

1. php_mongodb-1.13.0-8.1-ts-vs16-x64
2. php_mongodb-1.12.1-8.1-ts-vs16-x64
3. php_mongodb-1.12.0-8.1-ts-vs16-x64

and also added extension=php_mongodb.dll in the php.ini file.

I don't understand this warning and I have no clue how to resolve it.

***PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Can't load module 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mongodb.dll' as it's linked with 14.29, but the core is linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0***

Please help me and Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this `composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: Thanks, I tried but didn't work.

Comment: Hurray !!  I am able to figure out the issue. It was a Composer issue. It was using an older version of PHP.  I just uninstalled the composer and Install back and pointed to the latest version of PHP  and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem and solved it running the PHP process as Administrator on Windows